# Differentiate between how objects are defined as key's

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have the following object

```
let object = {
    objA: new Number('100'),
    objB: {} 
}
```

If I put the primitive types in an array and use a for each loop comparing with the current key, is it possible to then duplicate the value reliably?

Context: I am trying to clone a JavaScript object but cloning the objA property just yields '{}' in objB (the clone)

Thanks

Comment: As `'100'` is a string, you should use `Number.parseInt('100')` instead of `new Number('100')`.

Comment: There’s no good reason to use `new Number` (a *primitive wrapper*), ever, and no reason to support treating the result like an actual number. Did you mean `Number('100')` without the `new`?

Comment: You can try `objB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objA))` to just clone the object. But you will get `objB = 100`

Comment: How are you trying to clone `objA`, can you show us that code please? `objB: {}` obviously doesn't create a number.